# TextView stops showing on device when gravity is set to it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working with a layout that contains a `LinerLayout` and a `TextView`. 
When I set the `gravity` attribute to the `TextView` it stops showing on the device, yet shows up on the android layout preview.

Here is the `xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grapher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how it looks on the preview screen

[image: Preview Screen]

Yet on the device it stops showing

[image]

But when I remove the `gravity` attribute it shows up on the device. **Why is this happening? How should I fix this?**

Comment: what if you use center|top gravity instead?

Comment: try making it android:layout_gravity="center|top"

Comment: Try @Benjamin suggestion. But I am curious why you use `layout_weight` in this case. What happens if you remove weights and make TextView layout_height="wrap_content" and LinearLayout layout_height="match_parent"?

Comment: Can please share your activity?

Comment: @SubramanianR there's nothing in the `Fragment` that affects the layout. Only `findViewById(int)`

Comment: @Manishika  Done that, same thing.

Comment: I have tried this code, it is working fine with my emulator and i can see the textview with text.

Comment: prometheuspk, did you try center|top as we suggested, what was the output then?

Answer (score 0):

i used the linear layout as the parent layout and it working both on emulator and on real device.. this is the xml:-->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/grapher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.9"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

please use the linear layout as parent and if there is any issue please let me know fast.

Comment: My parent is `linearlayout` too

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProductName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/grapher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```